# How do I add a footer row in a WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

How Do I Add a footer row in WPF datagrid? I had to add a row in a WPF datagrid for the sum of each column, I don't want to use any dll or telerik and some things like that only use Microsoft components to do this. I'm trying to do it this way:

```xaml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false" Background="Black">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Button Focusable="false"
                                        Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                                        Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey 
                                    ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, 
                                    TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                        Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
                                    ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, 
                                    Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                        Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />

                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
                ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, 
                Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />

                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="This is footer!"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I also tried adding a grid instead of textblock, but when resizing datagrid columns, they can't resize and looks very ugly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this.

```
<ScrollViewer  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Header1" Header="Header1"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Header2" Header="Header2"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Header3" Header="Header3"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <TextBlock></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock></TextBlock>                          
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=Header1,Path=ActualWidth}">
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Footer1"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=Header2,Path=ActualWidth}">
                <TextBlock Text="Footer2" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=Header3,Path=ActualWidth}">
                <TextBlock Text="Footer3" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: it works but it is very difficult to bind the footer with total of sum.suppose instead of footer3 i want to show the total sum of column or header 3 records then it is not binding.

Comment: you can create one additional property and display total sum to it.

Answer (score 8):

Answer By Heena Patil has some issues.
When the layout of the DataGrid changes, like when the scrollbar is visible or window resized. Then the position of footer changes.

> The concept is to set the margin-left and width of the footer TextBlocks
>   when the layout is updated.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGSalesINvoice" LayoutUpdated="DG_LayoutUpdated">
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DG_COL_IdSalesInvoice" Width="Auto" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding IdSalesInvoice}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DG_COL_CustomerName" Width="*" Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding CustomerName}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DG_COL_SalesInvoiceAmount" Width="Auto" Header="Invoice Amount">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding SalesAmount}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DG_COL_EditBtn" Width="50">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="btnEditCompany" Tag="{Binding IdSalesInvoice}">Edit</Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Background="GhostWhite">
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblTotal" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold">Total</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblTotalSalesInvoiceAmount" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold">0.00</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>

private void DGSalesINvoice_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thickness t = lblTotal.Margin;
    t.Left = (DGSalesINvoice.Columns[0].ActualWidth + 7);
    lblTotal.Margin = t;
    lblTotal.Width = DGSalesINvoice.Columns[1].ActualWidth;

    lblTotalSalesInvoiceAmount.Width = DGSalesINvoice.Columns[2].ActualWidth;
}
```

[image: Result]