# WPF Datagrid Footer by Code Behind => Access Column by Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I want make a footer to my DataGrid using this method:
[How do I add a footer row in a WPF datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521966/how-do-i-add-a-footer-row-in-a-wpf-datagrid)

But, i need to make this by code behind, and that's don't working.
I think it's because the binding of the grid can't find the column.

```
        private DataGridColumn dgInsertCol(ref int idx, DataGridColumn dgc, tblEtatRecapColonne pCol, string pBinding = "") {
        var dhHeadName = $"dgHead{pCol.Id}";
        dgc.SetValue(NameProperty, dhHeadName);
        dgc.HeaderTemplate = GetDtHeader(pCol, pBinding);
        dgc.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, (ckbSize.IsChecked.Value) ? DataGridLengthUnitType.Star : DataGridLengthUnitType.SizeToCells);
        dgMain.Columns.Insert(idx++, dgc);
        // Faire le footer associé
        var t = new TextBlock() { Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0), Text = pBinding, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(50, 100, 150)) };
        var g = new Grid() { MinWidth = 10 };
        g.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { ElementName = dhHeadName, Path=new PropertyPath("ActualWidth", null) }); // DataGridColumn
        g.Children.Add(t);
        pnlDgFooter.Children.Add(g);
        return dgc;
    }

            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dgMain" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" LoadingRow="dgMain_LoadingRow" MouseDown="dgMain_MouseDown" Sorting="dgMain_Sorting"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
                Style="{StaticResource dg}" RowStyle="{StaticResource dgRow}" CellStyle="{StaticResource dgCell}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource dgColHeader}" RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource dgRowHeader}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Source={StaticResource cvsElmts}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <!--DataGrid.DataContext><Binding Source="{StaticResource tblUsers}"/></DataGrid.DataContext-->
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SendCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=dgMain}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
                <!-- Style for groups under the top level. -->
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel Background="LightBlue">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="30,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="rowBtnDetail"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Name="pnlDgFooter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `ElementName` at all? Set the `Source` of the Binding directly. Also, don't set `Path` twice, so either write

```
g.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        Source = dgc,
        Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth")
    });
```

or

```
g.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = dgc });
```